# java removing element from hashset breaks while loop and leaves nul error

Tags: java, hashset

i have a hashset of room objects that are made in another function based on user input and are added to the hashset. here, we iterate through the rooms in the hashset and then iterate through the users and increases the room count based on how many of them are in the room. this works perfectly except when a room needs to be deleted.log.error(ex.getMessage()); leaves a null error, and it doesnt continue to iterate through the rest of the elements and the stringbuilder is left empty. the next time sendroomlist fires though it adds the rooms and their count to the stringbuilder but i need it to do this all in one go any help at all to put me on the right track please

heres my hashset

```
 private Set<Room> rooms = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Room>());
```

heres where i'm having the problem if you need to see where i add the rooms to the rooms hashset lmk

```
      private void sendRoomList()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String strRoom;
    int roomCount = 0;
    int spaghetticount = 0;
   // Room objRoom;
    try
    {
        synchronized (rooms)
        {
  // {
       //     Iterator<Room> iterRoom = rooms.iterator();
         //   while (iterRoom.hasNext())
           // {
   //             Room s = (Room) iterRoom.next();
        //        if ( (s.getName().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(roomName)) )
       // { return true;

       // }
            //Iterator<String> iterRoom = rooms.iterator();
               Iterator<Room> iterRoom = rooms.iterator();

                    while (iterRoom.hasNext())
            {
                //Room s = (Room) iterRoom.next();
                Room objRoom = (Room) iterRoom.next();
                strRoom = (String) objRoom.getName();
                synchronized (sessions)
                {
                    roomCount = 0;
                    Iterator<IoSession> iterSessions = sessions.iterator();

                    while (iterSessions.hasNext())
                    {
                        IoSession s = (IoSession) iterSessions.next();
                        if (s.isConnected())
                        {    
                            if (s.getAttribute("room").toString().equalsIgnoreCase(strRoom))
                            {

                                roomCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (roomCount <= 0 && strRoom != defaultRoom)
                {
                  synchronized (rooms)
                    {
                     rooms.remove(objRoom);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.append(strRoom + "|" + roomCount + "~");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    log.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
    broadcastRoomList(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iterRoom.remove() instead of rooms.remove(objRoom).

Comment: are you sure? this is my hashset and i need to remove it from this one too
    private Set<Room> rooms = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Room>());

Comment: iterRoom is an iterator that iterates over the rooms hashset. Calling the remove() method in it will remove the object from the corresponding hashset. This is the only correct way to remove an object from a collection while iterating over it.

Comment: i'm going to try it right now and i'll get back to you if it doesnt fix my issue. Thank you very much for the very quick and informative response

Comment: it worked thank you so much man!! i can't believe how simple that was. i've spent hours upon hours of googling trying to figure out what to do